# How to compile go code that doesn't conform to the `go get` pattern

Tags: go

I have Go installed on my system and can install packages that conform to the `go get ...` pattern. As you can see [in this link](http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.824/2014/labs/lab-1.html), MIT is using Go for one of its courses. However, installing the provided code isn't as easy as running `go get ...` and having all the packages installed in the proper place.  Rather, it asks you to clone the repository and then "Compile the initial software we provide you and run it with the downloaded input file". As you can also see, it instructs the user to export a GOPATH (I think assuming that the students are using Go for the first time)

```
 git clone git://g.csail.mit.edu/6.824-golabs-2014 6.824

    $ add 6.824
    $ export GOPATH=$HOME/6.824
    $ cd ~/6.824/src/main
    $ go run wc.go master kjv12.txt sequential
```

When I clone the repo and run `go run wc.go master kjv12.txt sequential` from `/src/main` it can't find the packages. The source code (for example, the `wc.go` file that was supposed to be run),  seems to assume the packages are in the same directory. This is the wc.go file that's in `/src/main` and which needs `/src/mapreduce`

```
import "os"
import "fmt"
import "mapreduce"
import "container/list"
```

What's the best/easiest/most convenient way to compile code that's distributed like this? One way I can think of is to `cd` into each package, run `go install` and then change the import path in each file that requires these packages, which is very time consuming and I'm assuming is not the recommended way, and I also don't want to change the GOPATH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, following the [MIT 6.824 instructions](http://css.csail.mit.edu/6.824/2014/labs/lab-1.html),

```
$ cd $HOME
$ git clone git://g.csail.mit.edu/6.824-golabs-2014 6.824
Cloning into '6.824'...
remote: Counting objects: 108, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (107/107), done.
remote: Total 108 (delta 40), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (108/108), 1.61 MiB | 561.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (40/40), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd 6.824
$ ls
Makefile  src
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/6.824
$ cd ~/6.824/src/main
$ go version
go version devel +01dfd37363e9 Fri Aug 22 22:22:16 2014 +0400 linux/amd64
$ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="6"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/peter/6.824"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/peter/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/peter/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
$ go run wc.go master kjv12.txt sequential
# command-line-arguments
./wc.go:12: missing return at end of function
./wc.go:16: missing return at end of function
$
```

What output do you get when you run these commands?

---

For `wc.go`,

```
import "os"
import "fmt"
import "container/list"
```

are found in `$GOROOT` and

```
import "mapreduce"
```

is found in $GOPATH.

---

Use

```
$ export GOPATH=$HOME/6.824
```

Comment: The reason why this concerned me was the following: This is what it normally says when I run `env`: `"/Users/myname/go/"`. However, with this export it now says `"/Users/myname/6.824"`. Isn't this a problem that it's overwriting the existing GOPATH? Also, I want it added permantly to my gopath like this "/Users/myname/go/6.824` not just one terminal session. `go get` adds it permanently to the path in the desired location, but can't do that now